# How to secure and allow authentication with ElasticSearch?

Tags: security, authentication, elasticsearch

I have IP to ES:

```
http://1.2.3.4:9200/index/_search?size=1000&q=*:*
```

and me or anyone can access to see data once we have IP:

```
  {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "from" : 0, "size" : 3000
    }
```

But how can I secure ElasticSearch cluster so that even if you know IP - can not access data without Username/Password?

Thanks.

Comment: Security features are part of the xpack commercial package. However you may have a loot at https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch/

Comment: @gusto2 Basic Authentication is now part of the Basic License, which is free.

Answer (score 0):

The basic authentication on Elasticsearch is now part of the Elastic Stack Basic License, which is free, you just need to use versions 6.8.X or 7.1.X and configure the authentication using the native realm.

This post on the [elastic blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free) has more information about the security features, and this part of the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/elasticsearch-security.html) explains how to configure the security on elastic.

Answer (score 0):

The basic authentication is free in Elastic Stack version 6.8.X and 7.1.X now.

If you use other Elastic Stack version, You can use own proxy basic authen. For example Nginx on Linux or IIS on windows.

PS.  For more secure you can set HTTPS for Elastic API on proxy setting. (^^)